# Spring callback when Entity exits @Transactional context?

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactional, hibernate-onetomany, entitylisteners

Does Spring have any hooks to call a method on an entity or an entity listener for each entity at the exit of a transactional context?

We're using Spring and Hibernate to manage a bunch of entities that we also index for searching. We currently use an entity listener with Hibernate's @PreUpdate method to perform a reindex when an entity is created or modified. Of course, this event only fires when one or more of the entity's own properties (i.e., values in its database row) is updated.

The problem occurs when an entity has a @OneToMany mapping for non-trivial child properties. When one of those child properties is updated, the PreUpdate callback is *not* called on the parent entity.

We already track when properties are updated, but we want to wait until all updates are
complete before triggering a reindex. What is the best place to put such a reindex call? PreUpdate works well for most cases, but this wrinkle led me to wonder if there was a hook for when an entity leaves a @Transactional scope. Alternatively, is there a Hibernate way to trigger a callback on the parent when a OneToMany child is persisted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think aspect is for rescue. have a look section 10.5.8 Advising transactional operations [Advising transactional operations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html) in spring documentation this will help you to write aspect around @Transactional method and then you do indexing.